# Android Bluetooth logging filling up logcat

Tags: android, bluetooth

I used the Bluetooth Chat example as a starting point to implement a BT connection from my phone to an embedded device.  I am able to successfully connect to the device but once the connection is made the logcat is getting overrun by a massive amount of logging.  I did not see this type of logging when first doing the BT chat app phone to phone.

Here is what is repeated over and over.  It basically makes the logcat unusable.  So far I haven't found a way to configure the logging or why it's logging so much.  Any insights would be appreciated.

```
03-08 14:29:04.941: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket.cpp(11422): availableNative
03-08 14:29:04.957: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket(11422): available
03-08 14:29:04.957: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket.cpp(11422): availableNative
03-08 14:29:04.971: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket(11422): available
03-08 14:29:04.976: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket.cpp(11422): availableNative
03-08 14:29:04.989: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket(11422): available
03-08 14:29:04.991: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket.cpp(11422): availableNative
03-08 14:29:05.016: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket(11422): available
03-08 14:29:05.016: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket.cpp(11422): availableNative
03-08 14:29:05.034: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket(11422): available
03-08 14:29:05.036: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket.cpp(11422): availableNative
03-08 14:29:05.050: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket(11422): available
03-08 14:29:05.051: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket.cpp(11422): availableNative
03-08 14:29:05.066: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket(11422): available
03-08 14:29:05.066: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket.cpp(11422): availableNative
03-08 14:29:05.081: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket(11422): available
03-08 14:29:05.081: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket.cpp(11422): availableNative
03-08 14:29:05.086: DEBUG/(2419): jw_if_rfcomm_cl_cback: jw_if_rfcomm_cl_cback event=BTA_JV_RFCOMM_READ_EVT
03-08 14:29:05.086: DEBUG/(2419): jv_forward_data_to_jni: BTA_JV_RFCOMM_DATA_IND_EVT bta hdl 2
03-08 14:29:05.086: DEBUG/(2419): bts_log_tstamps_us: [update stats] ts    1263504, bta hdl 2, diff 01263504, tx_q 1 (1), rx_q 0 (0)
03-08 14:29:05.086: DEBUG/BLZ20_WRAPPER(11422): blz20_wrp_poll: transp poll : (fd 41) returned r_ev [POLLIN ] (0x1)
03-08 14:29:05.086: DEBUG/BLZ20_WRAPPER(11422): blz20_wrp_poll: return 1
03-08 14:29:05.086: DEBUG/BLZ20_WRAPPER(11422): blz20_wrp_read: read 122 bytes out of 1024 on fd 41
03-08 14:29:05.101: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket(11422): read
03-08 14:29:05.101: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket.cpp(11422): readNative
03-08 14:29:05.101: DEBUG/ASOCKWRP(11422): asocket_read
03-08 14:29:05.106: INFO/BLZ20_WRAPPER(11422): blz20_wrp_poll: nfds 2, timeout -1 ms
03-08 14:29:05.117: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket(11422): available
03-08 14:29:05.121: DEBUG/BluetoothSocket.cpp(11422): availableNative
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In DDMS you can filter things out by using the debug, info, error, warning buttons and you can also create a special filter to only show things that you are interested in. Don't think there is any bluetooth setting to turn off logging that you could use.

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the answer.  Thanks

Comment: Follow up - I think that I may be running into a phone issue as well.  I do not get the excessive logging when running the code on a G1 phone.  Both my Galaxy S and the G1 are running Android 2.1 update 1.

Comment: I've seen the same problem. It's limited to Samsung devices. They should turn off debugging spam before shipping.

Comment: Also see this on the MyTouch 4G slide, Bluetooth messages floods when I connect to a data BT device and logs the byte buffer message size in 50 byte increments.  I send 8k bytes per sec.  so I get 800 lines of logcat messages per sec!!

Comment: I have both a Samsung Illusion i110 and a MyTouch 4G slide that is having the same issues.  I counted about 1000 messages per second of debug garbage.  Worse the Samsung has a bug in it where when you disconnect the bluetooth  it floods at 2000 messages per sec Error code that says line 1172 in btapp_bts.c errored.  Wish they'd roll out an update to comment out these two and fix the bugs.

Comment: Filtering isn't an option when logcat is filled with thousands or garbage logs. Android Studio is not able to process them all and the 'normal' logs are swallowed by the buffer length in a matter of seconds...

Answer (score 5):

After playing with my Arduino Board + Bluetooth-Adapter I tryed to implement the Bluetooth-Code from [MATT BELL'S BLOG](http://bellcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/android-and-arduino-bluetooth-communication/). The Problem is the following Code:

```
//final Handler handler = new Handler();
workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
        {
            try {
                int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                {
                    //Log.d(TAG,"bytesAvailable: "+bytesAvailable + " readBufferPosition: "+readBufferPosition);
                    byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                    mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);

                    for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                    {
                        byte delimiter = 0x0A;     // /n bzw. LF
                        byte b = packetBytes[i];
                        if(b == delimiter)
                        {
                            byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                            System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                            final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                            //final String data = new String(readBuffer);
                            readBufferPosition = 0;

                            Log.d(TAG,""+data);

//                                            //The variable data now contains our full command
//                                            handler.post(new Runnable()
//                                            {
//                                                public void run()
//                                                {
//                                                    //myLabel.setText(data);
//                                                    Log.d(TAG,""+data);
//                                                }
//                                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Exeption 2: "+e.getMessage());
                stopWorker = true;
            }
        }
    }
});
workerThread.start();
```

Calling the following function results in *huge* Spam in logCat

```
int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
```

**LogCat:**

PS: The timestamps are in fact of the fixed version. Not using the fix will will result in a spam every **5ms** effectivly blocking my whole Log

```
03-17 18:43:06.615: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:06.715: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:06.820: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:06.920: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:07.020: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:07.120: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:07.220: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:07.320: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:07.420: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:07.520: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:07.620: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:07.725: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:07.825: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:07.925: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
03-17 18:43:08.025: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(8871): availableNative
```

My current fix is adding the following code at the end of the *while* loop resulting in reduction of the spam.

```
try {
Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.d(TAG,"Exception Thread.sleep()");
}
```

I hope this will help some people with similar issues.

**Edit:** Currently I had to reduce the sleep-timer to 10ms bam .. SPAM

```
03-18 15:50:18.470: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(3482): availableNative
03-18 15:50:18.470: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(3482): availableNative
03-18 15:50:18.470: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(3482): availableNative
03-18 15:50:18.470: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(3482): availableNative
03-18 15:50:18.470: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(3482): availableNative
03-18 15:50:18.470: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(3482): availableNative
03-18 15:50:18.470: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(3482): availableNative
03-18 15:50:18.470: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(3482): availableNative
03-18 15:50:18.470: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(3482): availableNative
03-18 15:50:18.470: VERBOSE/BluetoothSocket.cpp(3482): availableNative
```

Comment: Did you found any way to come over this? I am too struggling for the exact issue.

Answer (score 3):

This must be an error, and a serious one:

- either Logcat only shows this debug print sometimes - although my code always comes across it
- or the Bluetooth chip runs loose sometimes...(more likely).

Just turning the log level to debug from verbose **won't** change the fact there is an enormous amount of data transferred to Logcat, blocking all normal logs...

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon this: after 3 years this log clogging is still present - at least on my Samsung GT-I8190 (4.1.2).

The culprit is `mmInputStream.available()`

One way around this is not to use it `available()` method. Instead of:

```
int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();

if(bytesAvailable > 0)
{...
```

You could use something like the code below to awoid log clogging...

```
int i = -1;
while((i=mmInputStream.read())!=-1)
{                           
  char c=(char)i;

  // you can do your buffering here...
  Log.i("readBT","have char: "+c);
}
```

This code below also works on phones with this nasty bug. It should probably be revise though since it is just a quick & dirty fix:

```
void beginListenForData()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {                
               while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
               {
                    try 
                    {
                        int i = -1;
                        while((i=mmInputStream.read())!=-1)
                        {
                           byte b=(byte)i;

                           Log.i("readBT","have byte: " + b);

                           if ( (readBufferPosition >= 1023) || (b == delimiter) )
                           {
                               byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                               System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                               final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "UTF-8");
                               readBufferPosition = 0;

                               handler.post(new Runnable()
                               {
                                   public void run()
                                   {
                                       myLabel.setText(data);
                                   }
                               });                             
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                           }                           
                        }                       
                    } 
                    catch (IOException ex) 
                    {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
               }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();
    }
```

Comment: Read methods also have a (double) log issue: 
`D/BluetoothSocket: read in:  android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@4235d498 len: 1
D/BluetoothSocket: read out:  android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@4235d498 ret: 1`

Answer (score 1):

"avaliableNative" has a Verbose priority. To get rid of the message (and all verbose messages as well) use a "*:D" parameter as the last logcat parameter. Similar thing can be achieved in Eclipse by using the "debug" priority in the combo box next to the floppy disk icon.